error handling outputs html instead json in express
i followed the express.js 's tutorial to make a simple errorhandler
function clientErrorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
  if (req.xhr) {
    console.log('clienterrorhandler', err);
    res.status(500).send({ error: 'Something failed!' });
  } else {
    next(err);
  }
}

app.use(clientErrorHandler);

This is how I defined the error
import { StatusCodes } from 'http-status-codes';
import CustomAPIError from './custom-errors';

class UnauthenticatedError extends CustomAPIError {
  constructor(
    public message: string,
    public statusCode: number,
  ) {
    super(message, statusCode);
    this.statusCode = StatusCodes.UNAUTHORIZED;
  }
}
export default UnauthenticatedError;

auth Middleware
export const auth = asyncHandler(
  async (
    req: AuthenticatedRequest,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction,
  ): Promise<void> => {
    try {
    } catch (err) {
      throw new UnauthenticatedError(
        'There is no token atached to the Header.',
        StatusCodes.UNAUTHORIZED,
      );
    }
  },
);

The key problem is when the error occurs, the client side receives a html based error, that my errorhandler doesn't work out
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Error: Not Athorized token expired, Please Login again.<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at authMiddleware.ts:44:15<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at asyncUtilWrap 


You're relying on the req.xhr field. This is only set when the request contains the header
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

From memory, only jQuery's $.ajax() sets this by default; Axios / XMLHttpRequest and fetch() do not.
Instead of using this non-standard header (that also causes cross-origin requests to become non-simple), you should use content negotiation via the Accept header.
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  if (req.accepts('application/json')) {
    console.log('clienterrorhandler', err);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Something failed!' });
  }
  return next(err);
});

and on the client-side
fetch(url, {
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
  },
});

